# Función para eliminar una vocal de una cadena python

Tags: python, funciones

Estoy intentando crear una función usando find, map,reduce, filter o lambda. Debo introducir una cadena  y que salga esa cadena sin las vocales. Llego haciendolo sin función. ¿Podeis orientarme un poco? Gracias

```
#Quitar Vocal
vocales="aeiou"
texto=input()
texto1=""
for letra in texto:
    if letra not in vocales:
       texto1=texto1+letra
print(texto1)
```

Comment: ¿Y `filter()` no está permitida? Porque ya que parece que te piden que uses programación funcional, `filter()` sería la función indicada para este problema.

Comment: `nueva = ''.join([x for x in cadena if x.lower() not in "aeiou"])`. De nada.

Comment: @CandidMoe Claro, una comprensión es la solución natural, pero parece que el OP está constreñido a usar "find, map, reduce o lambda". De esas tres, reduce podría usarse (con una lambda) pero es innecesariamente complejo y feo. Puestos a usar programación funcional en lugar de comprensiones, yo usaría `filter`, pero esa parece no estar en la lista de "permitidas", de ahi mi anterior comentario.

Comment: @abulafia. Habla mal de su profesor el que no sea capaz de inventar un ejercicio donde esas funciones apliquen naturalmente, donde no haya alternativa excepto aplicar esas funciones. Entonces reciclan los mismos ejercicios básicos, pero con restricciones ... malo, malo.

Comment: SI filter está permitida.

Comment: Tanto Abulafia como yo tenemos dudas sobre por que lo intentas hacer con esas funciones y que está permitido. Hay alguna restriccion o puedes usar bucles for y comprensión de lista?

Comment: Creo que debe ser algo así: nuevo = list(filter(lambda i: i != "aeiou", cadena)) Pero me falla :(

Comment: @LorenzoPáez Pero... ya he dado una respuesta ¿no te ha servido?

Comment: letra =["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

vocal = list(map(lambda c: str(c).replace("o",""), letra))
print (vocal)

Answer (score 1):

### Solución con expresiones generadoras

El bucle que has escrito puede traducirse sin mucho esfuerzo a una versión con "expresión generadora".

Este es un tipo de expresión con la siguiente sintaxis:

```
(expr for var in iterable if condicion)
```

Esas expresiones producen otro iterable, cuyos elementos son los resultados de evaluar `expr` para cada iteración del `iterable` de entrada que cumpla la `condicion`. Por ejemplo, si el iterable de entrada es el `texto`, podrías escribir:

```
(letra for letra in texto if letra.lower() not in "aeiou")
```

El resultado de esa expresión se lo puedes pasar a `"".join()` para que te lo reúna de nuevo en una cadena.

Si en vez de paréntesis pones corchetes `[]` alrededor de la expresión generadora, entonces tendrás una *comprensión de listas* que hace lo mismo pero almacena en una lista los resultados. Para el caso de pasárselo a `join()` no es necesario crear esa lista intermedia, y de ese modo se ahorra un poco de memoria), por lo que puedes hacer directamente:

```
texto1 = "".join(letra for letra in texto if letra.lower() not in "aeiou")
```

### Solución funcional

Sin embargo en tu ejercicio planteas un enfoque "funcional" ya que indicas que debe hacerse con una de las funciones siguientes: `map()`, `reduce()`, `filter()` y con el uso de `lambda`.

En este enfoque no escribes bucles (ni explícitos ni en expresiones generadoras), sino que descansas en el hecho de que las funciones mencionadas hacen esos ciclos por tí. En concreto:

- `map(f, iterable)` itera por el iterable, le aplica la función `f()` a cada elemento y devuelve otro iterable con los resultados de cada `f(elemento)`. El iterable resultado tendrá tantos elementos como el iterable de entrada, pero transformados a través de `f()`. No nos sirve aquí, pues queremos que el resultado tenga menos letras que la entrada.
- `reduce(f, iterable)` itera por el iterable y le pasa a `f()` dos parámetros: el valor actual leido del iterable, y el resultado de la iteración anterior. Es decir, `anterior = f(anterior, elemento)`. Típicamente se usa para reducir todos los iterables a un solo valor (por ejemplo sumarlos todos). Tampoco es adecuado a este problema aunque podría usarse haciendo algunos trucos horribles.
- `filter(f, iterable)` itera por el iterable, llamando a `f()` para cada uno, y crea otro iterable que contiene solo los elementos para los cuales `f(elemento)` salga `True`, Esta es la que necesitamos.

En nuestro caso la función `f()` sería una que retorne `True` si el elemento debe ser conservado, es decir, si no es una vocal.

La función puede escribirse "*in situ*" (en la propia llamada a `filter()`) sin necesidad de escribir una función aparte, si hacemos uso de una **expresión `lambda`**, que es una forma super-abreviada de escribir una función cuando ésta es tan simple que no tiene dentro estructuras de control, sino un mero `return`.

En nuestro caso la función que necesitamos sería así:

```
def es_consontante(letra):
   return letra.lower() not in "aeiou"
```

Y en forma de lambda sería por tanto así (no se pone el `return`):

```
lambda letra: letra.lower() not in "aeiou"
```

De modo que la solución a tu problema sería:

```
texto1="".join(filter(lambda x: x.lower() not in "aeiou", texto))
```